# Existential types as module types in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Given a type

```
type 'a ty
```

and a module type

```
module type TY = (sig  type a  val x : a ty  end)
```

I can define

```
let toTY (type b) (x' : b ty) : (module TY) =
(module struct
  type a = b
  let x = x'
end)
```

and I would like to define a function (although this doesn't typecheck)

```
let ofTY (m : (module TY)) : m.a ty = ???
```

with the intended effect that whenever `m : (module TY)` then `ofTY m : m.a ty`, so
trying to define it as

```
let ofTY (type b) (m : (module TY with type a = b)) : b ty = ...
```

does not have the intended effect.

What is the appropriate way of defining `ofTY`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OCaml is not dependently typed, thus a type cannot depend on a value. In other words, since `m` is a value, `m.a` cannot be a type.

Another way to see the issue is that in the module type

```
module type TY = sig
  type a
  val x: a ty
end
```

the value `x` is existentially quantified by type `a`, and there is no way to remove such existential quantification, at most you can express it in different ways.